# How can I permanently get rid of the "Install Missing Plugins" bar at the top of my Firefox window?

Tags: firefox, browser, plugins

On certain websites that require you to have a plug-in installed with Firefox a banner at the top will appear stating:

"Additional plugins are required to display all the media on this page."

with a button to the right "Install Missing Plugins". Since I'm at work, I cannot install plugins, so I've been trying to get rid of it permanently but haven't found a successful way. The plug-in it wants me to install is Adobe Flash. Every time I refresh the page, it will return.

Just in case my Firefox version is: 3.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type "about:config" in your browser.

Search for "plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin;false" and change it to true.

(Be careful when editing in about:config mode).

Comment: Sweet. Do I have to restart Firefox after making the change?

Comment: Yep. Now I re-read your question, and don't know if you'll have permission to edit this configuration in your environment either. :/ If so, I do believe ChriF answer would be more adequate. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Two solutions spring to mind:

1) Ask your IT department if you can have Flash installed.

I know it's not what you've asked for, but there are so many sites that use Flash these days, it's almost a requirement to have it installed, and indeed may well be for the site you're visiting.

2) Install AdBlock and then add the Flash content it wants to display to the block list. I think you should be able to install this. If not talk to your IT dept again - I can't see them objecting to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Enter "`about:config`" into the Firefox address bar. Get past the nag screen and then type "`missing_plugin`" into the filter box. Now you should see only one single variable that is currently set to `false`. Set it to `true` and you should be done.